# Restricted generic type hint in Python

Tags: python, type-hinting, typing

I want to create a factory method like here.

```
class A:
    ...

class B(A):
    def f(self):
        ...

class C:
    ...

def factory(cls):
    return cls()
```

But I want to add some type hints with two requirements:

- Only subclasses of `A` are allowed as arguments of `factory`.
- When `B` is passed, it is correcly detected that `factory(B)` is instance of `B`, ie. `factory(B).f()` is allowed while `factory(A).f()` is not.

#### Attempt 1

Use `Type` from `typing` module.

```
from typing import Type

class A:
    ...

class B(A):
    def f(self):
        ...

class C:
    ...

def factory(cls: Type[A]):
    return cls()

factory(A)  # Ok
factory(B)  # Ok
factory(C)  # Fail
factory(A).f()  # Fail
factory(B).f()  # Fail -- Wrong!
```

This one correctly detects that `C` is not suppose to be passed as argument of `factory`. However, `factory(B).f()` is not allowed by the type-checker.

#### Attempt 2

Use `TypeVar`.

```
from typing import TypeVar, Type
T = TypeVar('T')

class A:
    ...

class B(A):
    def f(self):
        ...

class C:
    ...

def factory(cls: Type[T]) -> T:
    return cls()

factory(A)  # Ok
factory(B)  # Ok
factory(C)  # Ok -- Wrong!
factory(A).f()  # Fail
factory(B).f()  # Ok
```

It is well inferred that `factory(B).f()` is fine, while `factory(A).f()` is not. However, the generics is without restriction, ie. factory(C) is Ok as well.

#### Attempt 3

Add constraint to `T`.

```
from typing import TypeVar, Type

class A:
    ...

class B(A):
    def f(self):
        ...

class D(A):
    ...

class C:
    ...

T = TypeVar('T', A)
def factory(cls: Type[T]) -> T:
    return cls()


factory(A)  # Ok
factory(B)  # Ok
factory(C)  # Fail
factory(A).f()  # Fail
factory(B).f()  # Ok
```

This looks promising and at least PyCharm properly handles all cases. But for practical use is this solution actually the worst - `A single constraint is not allowed` error arises, though, it is not exactly clear why. In PEP 484, there is only a brief line saying 'There should be at least two constraints, if any; specifying a single constraint is disallowed.'

Is there any nice solution to this? I have only something like adding a 'dummy' class `_A`, a blank subclass of `A`, and putting it as another constraint to have something like this.

```
_A = NewType('_A', A)
T = TypeVar('T', A, _A)
def factory(cls: Type[T]) -> T:
    return cls()
```

But I don't really consider it as a nice solution.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Art thou a Scala veteran?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using a `TypeVar` with a `bound` seems to work:

```
from typing import Type, TypeVar

class A:
    ...

class B(A):
    def f(self):
        ...

class C:
    ...

AnyA = TypeVar("AnyA", bound=A)

def factory(cls: Type[AnyA]) -> AnyA:
    return cls()


factory(A).f()  # error: "A" has no attribute "f"
factory(B).f()  # ok!
factory(C)      # error: Value of type variable "AnyA" of "factory" cannot be "C"
```

Answer (score 2):

[The documentation about `TypeVar`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypeVar) says:

> ...a type variable may specify an upper bound using `bound=<type>`. This means that an actual type substituted (explicitly or implicitly) for the type variable *must be a subclass of the boundary type*

This looks exactly like what you want, so you can just write:

```
T = TypeVar('T', bound=A)
```

Comment: Oh, sure.. I completely miss it. Thank you!